# Show that $1-x-x^n+x^{n+1}$ is exactly divisible by $1-2x+x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Show that $1-x-x^n+x^{n+1}$ is exactly divisible by $1-2x+x^2$

First I rearrange both expressions into highest terms first: $x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1, x^2-2x+1$

Then I factor $x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)(x-1)$

Since we know for a fact that $x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1$ is exactly divisible by $(x-1)(x-1)$ with no remainder (this is what the problem statement tells us), it logically follows that $x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1$ should be divisible by $(x-1)$ with no remainder.

Hence

$$
\begin{array}{c|l|c}
x-1 & x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1 & x^n-1 \newline
 &x^{n+1}-x^n & \newline
\hline
&-x+1 & \newline
& -x+1  & \newline
\hline
& 0  & \newline
\end{array}
$$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1}{x-1} = x^n-1$

Am I doing this correctly? I'm not very comfortable when it comes to proofs. Also what I said earlier: "it logically follows that $x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1$ should be divisible by $(x-1)$ with no remainder." is more intuition on my part. How can this intuition be stated and/or proved with rigor? I'm not even sure what the formal mathematical principle is for this. Thanks.

Comment: $1-x-x^n+x^{n+1}=(1-x)-x^n(1-x)=(1-x^n)(1-x)$

Comment: Yes you are on the right track. You only need to show that $x^n-1$ is also divisible by $x-1$.

Comment: When you say "we know for a fact that...(this is what the problem statement tells us)", you're assuming that the thing you've been asked to prove is true. This thought process might help you *find* the requested proof, but you can't use it *in* that proof!

Comment: The division produces $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k$ with a zero remainder.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz, I am re-typing my note. The division of $\frac{x^{n}-1}{x-1}$ produces $x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+...+1$...How to show this?

Comment: So $(1-x^n)(1-x)$ divided by $(1-x)(1-x)$ yields $\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}$. This is the proof? But I can't understand how $\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ guarantees it will be exactly divisible for all $n$.

Comment: You can prove it by using the general equality $x^n-1=(x-1)Q(x)+R(x)$. Since $R(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than that of $x-1$, then it should be constant. Hence, $x^n-1=(x-1)Q(x)+R$. Now, it is a piece of cake to show that $R=0$.

Comment: So if $x=1$, then $R$ goes to $0$. How do you know $R(x)$ is a polynomial of a degree that is less than $(x-1)$? Thank you.

Comment: There is a general rule: a polynomial is divisible by $(x-a)^k$ if $p^{(l)}(a)=0$ for $0\le l\le k-1,$ where $p{(0)}=p.$  In your case $a=1$ and $k=2. $ Your example is pretty simple so that $(x-1)^2$ can be pull out explicitly so we may omit  the method of derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show that $x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1$ is *exactly* divisible by $x^2-2x+1$,  we have to find a polynomial $p(x)$ with
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1=\left(x^2-2x+1\right)p(x)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

You already found that $x^2-2x+1$ can be written as product of linear factors, so that (1) has the  representation
\begin{align*}
x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1=(x-1)^2p(x)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Thanks to a comment from @SineOf TheTime we can write the polynomial
\begin{align*}
x^{n+1}-x^n-x+1=x^n(x-1)-(x-1)=(x^n-1)(x-1)
\end{align*}
so that (2) can be written as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{(x^n-1)(x-1)=(x-1)^2p(x)}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

We deduce from (3) that we are looking for a polynomial $p(x)$ with
\begin{align*}
x^n-1=(x-1)p(x)
\end{align*}

> Since long division gives
> \begin{align*}
> \left(x^n-1\right):(x-1)=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
> We can write (3) using (4) as
> \begin{align*}
> (x^n-1)(x-1)=(x-1)(x-1)\color{blue}{\left(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1\right)}=(x-1)^2\color{blue}{p(x)}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows with $p(x)=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach.

Let $p(x) = 1 - x - x^n + x^{n + 1}$. Now if $(x - 1)^2$ is a factor of $p(x)$, that means $p(x)$ must have a double root at $x = 1$.

We could show this by finding the derivative, but there is a more elementary approach. We can actually prove something stronger: we can show that $p(x) \ge 0$ for all $x > 0$. This is because $p(x)$ can be factored as $(1 - x^n)(1 - x)$ as mentioned already. Now, if $x > 1, x^n > 1$ so both brackets will be negative. And if $0 < x < 1$, $x^n < 1$, both brackets will be positive and this is hence proven.

Hence $p(x)$ does not change sign in the neighbourhood of $x = 1$ and so there must be at least a double root. This proves that $p(x)$ is exactly divisible by $1 - 2x + x^2$.

Comment: It is always bad to downvote a contribution without providing an explicit reason! When will people stop this?

Comment: Here an upvote to also compensate a weird downvote (+1).

Comment: What's with the downvotes? Thanks to everyone who has upvoted however.